# How to know if the Form App open or not c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know how can I know if the Windows Form Application (C#) is open or that the client closed it?
(In my App I have a Windows Form Application (Form1) that allow the user to open another Forms (Form2). I want to know if the Form2 is open or close.)
I need to know that because I run the Form2 from a thread, and I want to make the thread runnig until the user close Form2.
Many thanks!

Comment: determine that within the same machine ?

Comment: Are you looking for an event at the end of the application?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a form of a given type is open in your application like this (using  LINQ):

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Count() > 0)
{
    // there is an instance of Form2 loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate on your question a bit more.  Are you talking about monitoring the application from another application?  Or that one form needs to know if another one is open?  Or a form needs to know when another form closes?

There are a couple of ways to monitor forms closing within the same application.

Calling `ShowDialog()` on your form instead of `Show()` will ensure that code following the `ShowDialog()` call doesn't get executed **until** the user closes the form.

The Form class has a `Visible` property, which returns true/false depending on whether the form is visible or not.

As for the application itself, there is an `ApplicationExit` event on the static `Application` class which gets called just before the application closes so you could listen to that event if, for example, you need to perform some clean-up on exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run only single instance of application, check [this](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html) link. 
There you will also see how to check whether a process is still active.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean MDI application with its child forms:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Form> SingleInstanceForms = new Dictionary<Type, Form>();

public Form ActivateForm<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    if (!this.SingleInstanceForms.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
    {
        T newForm = new T();
        //setup child
        newForm.MdiParent = this;
        newForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        //newForm.Icon = Icon;

        newForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SingleInstanceForms.Remove(sender.GetType());
        });

        this.SingleInstanceForms.Add(typeof(T), newForm);

        newForm.Show();
        this.Refresh();
    }

    Form formToActivate = this.SingleInstanceForms[typeof(T)];
    formToActivate.Activate();

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

    return formToActivate;
}
```

this will create the form child if hasn't been created yet and activate it if it has been created.

sample: `ActivateForm<dlgChildOne>();`

Comment: -1: this functionality is built in to WinForms. See the the Application.OpenForms collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx